# List Row Separator visibility setting not working? Xcode 13

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

Seems as though the visibility setting for the separators on lists is not working.. anyone know of a simple workaround?

Here is a piece of sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var listData = ["John", "Mack", "Bush"]
    var body: some View {
        List(listData, id: \.self) { name in
            Text(name)
        }.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
List {
    ForEach(listData, id: \.self) { name in
        Text(name)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}
```

Comment: Krishan This works good in light mode but in dark mode there is a black separator, looks like it is picking up some background. So it looks like separators.